# Quick charge adapter on not supported devices

Tags: charging

The adapter which comes with my new phone has `Qualcomm Quick Charge 3.0` label on it. The output reads: `5V-3A / 9V-2A / 12V-1.5A`. Is it safe to use it with my old phones? For example, if I have a very dated phone which only takes 5V-0.5A, will the adapter outputs 12V and fries it? And what would happen if I use that adapter with devices supporting fast charging technologies from other companies: `USB-PD` from USB-IF, `Pump Express` from Mediatek, `VOOC` from Oppo, and `SuperCharge` from Huawei?

Answer (score 0):

- > Is it safe to use it with my old phones?

It is safe. See [what happens if you plug a non QC 2.0 device into a QC 2.0 charger?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/158145)

- > And what would happen if I use that adapter with devices supporting fast charging technologies from other companies.

They all are *proprietary* technologies which vary in terms of what is changed to charge fast - Voltage, Current or both, apart from other factors. Details obviously are not in public domain. Therefore, they are not *guaranteed* to work on devices using other technologies, so one cannot predict whether it works or not.

OEM's don't recommend such practices. YMMV