# Is a specific charger needed to utilize 25W charging?

Tags: samsung, charging

I have a Samsung Galaxy S10 5G. Is it important for the charger and cable to have certain specifications to utilize the 25W charging capability?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/177788

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and it's usually the OEM supplied / recommended charger. Reasons:

For fast charging, the charger, cable and charging algorithm running inside the Phone need to be able to *negotiate* the right power (voltage & current) levels to charge the phone as designed. If any of these is not as per design, you won't get the fast charge as advertised.

- Charger: I don't know if your device supports Qualcomm or Exynos chip. If it is former, Qualcomm fast charger is backward compatible so any other Qualcomm charger would work but not fast charge. AFAIK, Exynos chip doesn't support this (Related [what happens if you plug a non QC 2.0 device into a QC 2.0 charger?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/158145/131553))
- USB cable needs to be of right capacity as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/142039/131553), else you may not get the right charging speed.

**TL:DR** Go with OEM recommended charger and cable if you want fast charging.

Comment: By not backwards compatible for Exynos, do you mean it will not fast charge if QC 3.0 is used on a QC 2.0 device whereas it will for Snapdragon?

Comment: As a policy Qualcomm declares this not Exynos (at least I never came across). // I haven't used Exynos phones for a long while but IIRC, it doesn't